# Android coding concept: AlertDialog as Activity?

Tags: android, coding-style, android-activity, android-alertdialog

If I'd like to launch from my MainActivity an AlertDialog which should be an Activity itself (because I need to pass information from an AlertDialog back to the MainActivity), what is the usual coding concept to do that? Do I have to extend Dialog in my DialogActivity or Activity or something? I'm not sure if the dialog itself should be the Activity or should the Activity somehow invoke an AlertDialog? Can you give me a hint.

My main problem is that I have 3 AlertDialogs in all, the last 2 depend on the choice of the first AlertDialog (so either nr2 or nr3 is called). And I have to pass information from the last dialogs back to the MainActivity, so I think the only clean way is to solve that with different Activities.

**[UPDATE]**
The solution is to create different Activities, which looks like the dialog (see accepted answer). The next problem was to pass some data from Activity A to B to C and the result back to A. This is very easy with Intents.
**A:** startActivityForResult(...)
**B:** startActivity(...); addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
**C:** setResult(...)
**A:** get data from onActivityResult(...)

Comment: Is there any issue with just normally showing one dialog, and then, via onClickListener, show one of the other dialogs?

Comment: @Nutomic Yes, because this would lead into unclear spaghetti code. The second dialog is more complicated and not just a simple list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a dialog theme that can be used to display an activity like a dialog.

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

Combined with startActivityForResult() and setResult() you should be able to create what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the preferred pattern is to use a [dialogfragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)

Comment: Maybe, but I develop for API level 7.

Comment: In that case use the support library: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/support-lib.html

Comment: Ok thanks, I will keep it in mind, but for now I'm already exchanging my ugly concept described in my OP by Activities was WarrenFaith proposed. This seems to work pretty good (for now).